# How can i collide two bodies without filtering(collision filtering)?

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, box2d, platformer

I have two bodies with fixtures. One is platform or ground and other is the player itself.I want to collide the player to the platform without bit filtering.How can i do that?I can see the rectangular ghost layer(like a rectangular box) and the box2d falling through it.I want the box2d to collide.

create player

Comment: Can you clarify why "without filtering" is a requirement of your case? Generally filtering helps performance by limiting the objects that can collide to just the objects we *want* to collide. It shouldn't prevent you from getting collisions between player and platform objects if you've configured your filters correctly. Do you need help configuring the filters' category & mask bits to ensure the player & platform can collide?

Comment: My teacher wants me to implement a different logic for collision detection which is the overlap method.I already have the code for bit filtering method but not for the overlap method.Can you help me achieve collision between player and ground using overlap method?

Comment: If that's what you want, then you should edit your question to say so, and define what you & your teacher mean by "the overlap method" to make sure we're all on the same page.

Answer (score 3):

set`fdef.isSensor = false;`
and `fixdef.isSensor = false;`

> A sensor shape collects contact information but never generates a collision response.

See FixtureDef documentation:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/FixtureDef.html#isSensor

You can use `.isSensor = true;` for an attack range of monster or a poisoned area

Comment: Thank you but I want the overlap method logic for collision detection between player and ground